# MYSQL new event if syntax in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin

I want to make an event that updates a fields in a table (start)

I created the event in phpMyAdmin and it gives me an error

```
BEGIN
    IF ((select sum(putNextDay) from machineTypes where no=1) = 1) THEN
     update prgs set start=CURDATE() where machineNo=1 and start=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and isDone=0;
     END IF
     END
```

it gives syntax error near END

Comment: nobody can suggest me what is the problem with the syntax? it is anoying that simple code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

on line 2 where you checked the if condition ,
   it take your `"if(xyz where=1)" condition as  "if (xyz=1) "` on your code,

it seem that you have assigned a value "1" in `"select sum(putNextDay) from machineTypes where no"` . 
try to apply the same in `''`.

hope this will helpful to you .
thanks